# Image editor that allows multiple, separate, simultaneous crop selections to be saved? (looking for both free & paid programs)

Tags: software-rec, image-editing, crop

Is there an image editor that allows you to select several crop regions and save each one as an individual file? Rather than having to load up the original image each time and do the cropping of each area and saving.

This would be useful if you are using the master, original image for several new purposes, or if you are scanning in several separate items at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with [Adobe Fireworks](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks/) or [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/family/). It's called Slicing there! 
You can see how it is done in this [Screencast](http://snook.ca/files/sc-export.mov)

**EDIT:** As you mentioned the task of separating scanned images, there is also a tool in PS only made for this prupose: [Crop and Straighten Photos](http://www.planetphotoshop.com/crop-and-straighten-photos.html).

Photoshop Elements has this kind of tool as well: [Divide Scanned Photos](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/PhotoshopElements/6.0/help.html?content=WSae2ea3b149d0c3591ae939f103860b3d59-7ee9.html)

Comment: Fine, +1, but any suggestions for a cheaper or free program as well?

Comment: @Rob - now you know what it's called in Photoshop you might find a free tool by searching for that term.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I would hope that slicing doesn't just mean extracting adjacent regions for making a clickable imagemap on a webpage. Ideally I'm interested in being able to draw several selection rectangles on the original image and then click save to save all of thses selections to individual files.

Comment: Gimp is another suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198612/any-free-html-image-slicer

Comment: I'll keep this question open for a few days for new answers, but at the moment I'm looking to accept this as the answer.

Comment: "Crop and Straighten Photos" and "Divide Scanned Photos" are automatic features - which is great for some scenarios I am looking for - but I'm not sure they allow manual rectangular selection of multiple regions.

Comment: Sounds like automated selection of multiple areas is the best available. Also slicing might provide manual selection. I'll accept this answer. Thanks räph and also ChrisF.

Answer (score 3):

I think this free utility may be what you are looking for :

http://www.bottomap.com/Software/A4B/A4B.html

Answer (score 1):

Something else you could try is [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com)...  I use this tool more than any other when it comes to cropping and screen shotting images.  Works like a dream and integrates well with other suites of graphics tools, like CS3.